# Urls with www-0 prefix

Tags: domain-name-system

I have noticed some sites with the url www-0. How is this possible? I assume this is a DNS trick? If so, what benefit does this have?

Any information on this is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What part confuses you?  Creating a dns name for `www-0` is the same as creating a name for `asdf`.

Comment: http://zomg.slashdot.org | http://omgponies.slashdot.org | http://do-not-click-this.slashdot.org | http://click-the-previous-link.slashdot.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [subdomain](http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm), just like www would be.

It's not really a "trick" but a rather a very basic feature of DNS.